# Библиотека pywin32 и pypiwin32 не найдены

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Захотел сделать голосового ассистента. Для его работы выбрал либу pyttsx3, для корректной работы которой необходима либа pywin32 и pypiwin32. Во время их установки в PyCharm последний сообщает что не находит их в сети. Пробовал установить через встроенного установщика пакетов, но ошибка всё таже, он их не находит/не видит. В чём может быть проблема? 
Python 3.8

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello! I'm Pyh")
engine.runAndWait()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего модуля больше нет, либо его переименовали (хотя мне кажется pip должен такое понимать)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в версии Python. В видео по которому я делал ассистента использовался Python 3.7.3 Использование 3.7.3 исправило ошибку

Comment: у вас был Python 3.7.3  и вы его исправили на Python 3.7.3  - это как?

Comment: @S.Nick с чего вы взяли что я использовал 3.7.3? В описании указано, что запуск кода производился на 3.8